# play local video file in jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer, video-player

I have a jwplayer on a html page which loads the videos fine from a cdn network or direct web URL. However I am looking to use locally (hard drive) stored videos to load on the web page. I understand that local resources are not allowed in the browser to load. I am looking for a work around on this.

Here is my code which I tried with locally stored video file.

```
jwplayer("video-player").setup({
                                            file: "file:///F:/video-file-name.mp4",
                                            image: "file:///F:/video-thumbnail.jpg",
                                            width: "100%",
                                            height: "100%",
                                            abouttext: "about text",
                                            aboutlink: "",
                                            logo: {
                                            file: "http://google-com/vid_logo.png"
                                            },
                                            autostart: true,
                                            primary: "flash",
                                            startparam: "start"

                                            }
                                        });
```

I also tried it with  file:// in the beginning of the path, but it won't work.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: "local resources are not allowed in the browser to load" - This is correct, this is not supported...

Comment: Thanks Ethan, so I assume you are saying there is no work around this?

Comment: Not that I know of, at least.